# Получение координат пока выполняется условие

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps

Необходимо получать координаты, пока выполняется условие. Пробовал так, но приложение крэшится.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    new GpsTask().execute();
}

public class GpsTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
        LatLng location;
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getBaseContext());
        while (true) {
            location = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

GPSTracker.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: приложите лог с эксепшеном

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что не могу. Устройство ZTE Geek2 не хочет работать со студией.

Comment: а в манифесте пермишны прописаны?

Comment: Конечно.

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Сложно определить в чем именно, попробуйте на эмуляторе сбилдить раз девайс не видится..

Comment: вопрос такой, чего вы хотите добиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в цикле

```
while(true)
```

Измените условие на примерно такое:

```
if (getLatitude() != null && getLongitude() != null) {
    location = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return "";
}
```

**Обновление**

В чем проблема? Сделайте проверку в цикле *while*, на условие нормально,  а не просто *while (true)*.

```
while((getLatitude() != null && getLongitude() != null) {
    location = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно получать координаты динамически. Т.е. до тех пор, пока условие выполняется координаты должны  обновляться, а на карте менялось изображение